# in mqtt qos1 i want to set dup flag true i dont know im not setting up dup falg can anybody explain this

Tags: client, mqtt, publish, mosquitto

```
bool dup = true;

// Publish the message with QoS 1
rc = mosquitto_publish(mosq, &mid, topic, strlen(message), message, 1, false);
if (rc != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to publish message: %s\n", mosquitto_strerror(rc));
    mosquitto_disconnect(mosq);
    return;
}
```

broker not giving

```
1684126876: Received PUBLISH from auto-FF3BAA6D-E659-460B-7332-244382A86BDE (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'example/topic', ... (12 bytes))
1684126876: Sending PUBACK to auto-FF3BAA6D-E659-460B-7332-244382A86BDE (m1, rc0)
```

i want d1 instead of d0

Comment: You need to add a LOT more detail to the question here, it's really not clear what you are asking. But you don't get to set the duplicate flag, the client code will do that it's self if needed, it is not something you control

Answer (score 1):

You do not manually set the `dupe` flag, the mosquitto client library (or any other MQTT client library) does this for you if the client needs to resend the message because the QOS1 handshake did not complete before the client was disconnected.

In that case when the client reconnects it will set the `dupe` flag and resend the message.

It is not something the end user code sets.